# How to calculate the distance between two points in projective plane

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, mathematical-physics, projective-geometry, projective-space

I have two homogeneous coordinates and I am trying to preserve the distance between two coordinates after various affine trasnformations. Should I calculate the angle between two points ? If so what is the formula to calculate the angle between two points or is there a distance formula other than the general euclidean plane? I found that euclidean distance formula will not preserve the distances

[what is the distance formula between two homogeneous coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106440/what-is-the-distance-formula-between-two-homogeneous-coordinates)

Comment: There's no such thing as distance in the projective plane -- it becomes projective partly from _ignoring_ the concept of distance.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So should I calculate the angle between the coordinates ?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to achieve. (Note that this angle, if I understand correctly what you mean, is not a projective invariant).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Assume I have a camera and I am moving towards the camera and away from the camera

Comment: What do you mean by “I am trying to preserve the distance […] after various affine transformations”? Is it that you have the affine trafos and want to *show* that they preserve distance? Or *check* whether they do preserve distance? Or is it that you want to append one more transformation in order to *make* distances as they were? If so, what kind of transformation? Or is it that you want to *tune* some parameters to ensure that distances are preserved? Do you want to preserve orientation as well, or may orientation be reversed?

Comment: @MvG I am trying to get back the original distance formula after same affine transformation performed on the homogeneous coordinates. Take the example of scaling after performing scaling on coordinates I want to apply distance formula and get back the original distance formula.